# Azure: Is there a way to switch from cloud service to VM without losing VIP?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I'm wondering if is possible to change currently running enviroment in CloudService(later CS) into VirtualMachine(later VM) deployment in Windows Azure without losing the assigned VIP in CS? Meaning that the VM would get the IP currently assigned to CS.

I'm aware that nowadays user can reserve public IP using the Azure PowerShell, could my goal be achieved somehow using that? Is it possible to reserve IP which is in use on CS deployment and then just undeploy and build VM environment using the reserved IP?`

Any way to deploy VM instance into CS Staging slot and then just swap VIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your concrete scenario - no.

First, because you cannot deploy VM and PaaS Roles in the same cloud service. This is by design.

Secondly, as per [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690120.aspx), there a few limitations to the Reserved IP Address as of today:

> - You must reserve the IP address first, before deploying.
> - At this time, you can’t go back and apply a reservation to something that’s already been deployed.

In theory you could:

1. Create an Empty Cloud service (without deployment)
2. Reserve a Public IP Address for this deployment
3. Deploy PaaS Role (web/worker)
4. Delete deployment from the cloud service
5. Deploy VM in the same cloud service

Then your VM deployed in step 5 would have same VIP as your cloud service deployed in step 3. This is the only way today to have same VIP for PaaS Role and VM while transitioning from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks! So basically I don't have means to accomplish what I need because the CS is already running and the IP assigned for it is not reserved. My options are to wait if Microsoft decides to add feature which will allow me to reserve IP address after deploying or just live with the idea that IP will change :)

Comment: or survive an IP change now by creating new Cloud Service, Assign Reserved IP, deploy your product, then update the DNS where needed. Potentially you can switch without down time, as you will have both deployment running until DNS changes propagade. Then have a reserved IP Address.

Comment: That would work on website type of system but unfortunately I have other functionality which have required IP based firewall rules. And unfortunately firewall rules based on domain name have not been quite commonly available.